# Chartjs - Graphics Value type float

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts

I have two graphs of the Chartjs and I need the values of both graphs to have broken values, for example (20,15);

Follow the graphics codes:

```
vm.chart = () => {
        vm.labels = ["D1", "VC1", "Internacional", "À cobrar", "0300", "Gratuita", "Locais"];
        vm.colors = [ '#f36e20', '#8aca7b', '#0bc4df', '#272343', '#389223', '#f1a80a', '#1e75eb'];
        vm.data = [10, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10, 30];
        vm.options = {
          data: [

            ]
        }
    }
```

html:

```
<canvas class="chart chart-doughnut" 
        chart-data="vm.data" 
        chart-labels="vm.labels" 
        chart-colors="vm.colors" 
        chart-options="vm.options" 
        ng-init="vm.chart()">
</canvas>
```

Second chart:

```
  vm.chart_gasto = () => {
        vm.data_labels = ["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","21","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31"];
        vm.data_gasto = [85,55,85,105,55,85,35,95,85,64,25,85,25,55,85,25,85,64,85,25,64,35,85,35,55,85,35,85,35,85,105];
        vm.data_colors = ['#8aacdf', '#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf','#8aacdf'];
        vm.data_options = {
            scales:{
                yAxes:[{
                    display: false
                }],
                xAxes:[{
                    display: true,
                    gridLines: {
                        color: 'rgba(255,255,255,.35)'
                    },
                    ticks: {
                        fontColor: '#9d9d9c'
                    }
                }]
            }
        }
    }
```

html:

```
  <canvas class="chart chart-bar" height="250px" 
          chart-data="vm.data_gasto" 
          chart-colors="vm.data_colors" 
          chart-labels="vm.data_labels" 
          chart-options="vm.data_options" 
          ng-init="vm.chart_gasto()">
  </canvas>
```

In addition to "broken" numbers, is there a possibility for the% value next to them?

Has anyone ever had to do something similar?

Comment: Worth to provide any plunker/Fiddle/Codepen with your issue

Comment: That, values like this, I have fixed values because I can not enter values with decimals.

Comment: The values of vm.datas are with fixed values, only necessary to put values with decimal places, example: 10.25, 10, 20, 10, 10, 10.50, 30 however it does not accept string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on [ChartJS documentation](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/tooltip.html#tooltip-callbacks):

> The tooltip label configuration is nested below the tooltip
>   configuration using the callbacks key. The tooltip has the following
>   callbacks for providing text. For all functions, 'this' will be the
>   tooltip object created from the Chart.Tooltip constructor.
>
> All functions are called with the same arguments: a tooltip item and
>   the data object passed to the chart. All functions must return either
>   a string or an array of strings. Arrays of strings are treated as
>   multiple lines of text.

In your case if I am not mistaken this applies to something like this:

```
  vm.options = {
    tooltips: {
      callbacks: {
        label: (tooltipItem, chart) => {
          const realValue = chart.datasets[tooltipItem.datasetIndex].data[tooltipItem.index]
          const customValue = realValue.toFixed(2).replace(".", ",") + '%';
          const label = chart.labels[tooltipItem.index] + ':';
          return label + customValue;
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Here's a [working fiddle with the code you shared](https://jsfiddle.net/4zm19j4u/2/).